# Calling a java class from an activity class

Tags: java, android

Hello everyone i have a question in android
How do i call a method in a non activity class from an activity class?
For eg:
I have an activity class

```
public class1 extends Activity
{
public void onCreate()
{
         class2.main(null);//this code does not work neither does creating an object 
}

}
//class 2
public class2 {
 public static void main()
 {//code
 }
  }
```

Comment: what you want to do in main function?

Comment: Why do you pass `null`? Just call `class2.main();` and it should work.

Comment: you really need to learn the basics of Java programming before trying to build an native Android application.

Comment: Sorry my main function is public static void main(Strings[] arg) and its a class to write to a pdf file based on the strings passed from class 1 which is an activity class but the avd keeps crashing if i try to call the method class2.main(null) or even if i had another method which is not main say public test() it still crashes

Answer (score 1):

The main method is not expecting any parameters so dont pass **null** to the method. see the code below:

```
  public Class1 extends Activity { 
        public void onCreate(){

                Class2.main(); // remove null
           }

    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public class Class2 { 
             public static void main() { //code } 
        }
```

You said that it doesnt create an **Object**, the main method is static which means it belongs to the **Class** not to any **Object**, thats why you don't have to create an **Object** of type **Class2**. If you want to create an **Object** of **Class** Class2 use the code below:

```
Class2 class2 = new Class2(); // Creating Object;
class2.main() // calling method here
```

If the **SomeClass** is in a different package you'll have to import it.

As a naming convention for class names start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have your `class2` in the same package as `class1` or you have made proper import statements at the top of your activity class file.

After you have done that, there are two ways to use a method from another class:

1st: Make an instance of class2 and call the method on it

```
Class2 class2instance = new Class2();
class2instance.method();
```

2nd: If your method is static, you can call it directly with the class name

```
Class2.staticMethod();
```

So, if you can edit your non-activity class, try making the method you want to use static, or create an instance of class and then call methods on it.

Also, in your code sample, the main method defined in `class2` isn't expecting any arguments, so drop the `null` in the method call.